# Understanding static video streaming

Tags: http, video-streaming, mp4

Let's for example look at the [video I found](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4) and open a network tab.

This is quite big video (150mb) as you can see. I don't want it to be fully downloaded, so browser asks server to get pertial content. Server responds with 206 status and sends asked amount of data. This is clear. But I don't understand the very first request.

```
Request URL: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4
Request Method: GET
Remote Address: 173.194.73.128:80
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Server response is:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: origin, range
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 158008374
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

It says that content length is 158008374 bytes(150mb). What? I don't feel that I just downloaded 150mb of data. What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser starts to to play a video, it doesn’t know anything about the file structure or size. So it starts to download. Once it sees that it’s a large file, and has enough information that is know where it can skip too, it closes the connection.